# Django Forms to values of html <input> field

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to access the values of a Bootstrap btn-group from Django and from the documentation I have found, it seems that you should use Forms in Django for such tasks.

This is what the html looks like, right now:

```
        <div class="col-md-6">
        {% for metric in metrics %}
            <input name="{{ metric.name }}" type="hidden" value="0"/>
        {% endfor %}
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            {% for metric in metrics %}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-checkbox-name="{{ metric.name }}">{{ metric.name }}</button>
            {% endfor %}
           </div>
        </div>
```

How can I use forms to get the values of the input fields?

Comment: Have you looked at the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django)?

Comment: Yes... but I can't understand how to link the form method in views.py to my html template. (The form method is called get_name in their example).

Comment: [This](http://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-use-python-django-forms/) might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is a basic example about using a form in django

**views.py:**

```
@login_required
def your_view(request):  # Add this code into your view
    if request.method == 'POST':       
        # So here you can do a loop over POST fields like this
        data_list = []  # We will insert all the inputs in this array
        for key in request.POST:  
            data_list.append(request.POST[key])
        # Here you can manage the the data_list and do whatever you need
        # The content of the data_list depend on your inputs
        # It could be string, integer....

    # YOUR VIEW CODE
```

**template (form example):**

```
<form action="." method="post" id="add_user_form"> 
    {% csrf_token %} 
    {% for metric in metrics %}
        <input type="text" name="{{ metric.name }}" placeholder="whatever you want"> 
    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="default"/>  # Submit button

</form>
```

`{% csrf_token %}` : You need to put this in every form you use

`action="."` : This make the post to the actual page

But anyway I strongly recommend you to check this [Django Forms Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) to unterstand better the logic, and also check the `ModelForms` because can save you a lot of time when you need to make a form for a model that exists in your Django Models

Answer (score 1):

You are'n forced to use django forms, this is just a way to get a sort of organization.

in you views toy can get the values sent to the server by using request.GET or request.POST, depending of the method of the form.

to get a list of values you have received just do a

```
print request.POST
```

request.POST is a dictionary, so you can get any value fron them by its key:

```
print request.POST['<key>']
```